# Python - most accurate time, timezone, calendar library/module

Tags: python, datetime, time

What is the most accurate library or module for python for time zone conversions, i.e. local time to UTC conversions, calendar day conversions that address many historic wartime time zone changes, timezone adoptions and splits, etc over the last couple of centuries?

Comment: Library recommendations are off topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

This is one that works great in most ways because it has some math components of it bundled in

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a site for opinion-based questions, so if your answer is "this is my personal favourite" then that's a clue the question is off-topic.

Comment: @kaya3 I edited it to better reflect why I like it, and I will not leave answers like "this is my personal favorite" anymore.

Comment: @ItsLogic Just read about it. Looks like it has accurate timezone keeping that I was looking for. thanks

Comment: @KapishM if it works for you please mark it as so. Cheers